# Downloading an APK from IIS 7.5 to downloads failing

Tags: android, apk, download

This code works when downloading from an apache server no problem. but when testing on using iis 7.5 currenlty installed on win7. it doesn't seem to work at getInputStream(); although the full address to the file is being shown when debuging and pasting that into the browser starts the download of the apk

Reading this site and the internet  have added MIME TYPE .apk application/vnd.android.package-archive

```
try {

                        URL url = new URL(prefs.getString("server_address", null) + "/updates/filename.apk");
                        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        c.setDoOutput(true);
                        c.connect();

                        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
                        File file = new File(PATH);
                        file.mkdirs();
                        File outputFile = new File(file, "filename.apk");
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len1 = 0;
                        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                        }
                        fos.close();
                        is.close();



                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```

Comment: you didn't check status: `int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();` could you add this code and tell us what do you get in code var?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't seem to work at getInputStream();"? have you checked the network communication, e.g. by using Wireshark on the server?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply code is 405

Comment: @robert wireshark is showing something interesting... although i have get its showing post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just get rid of this code:

```
      c.setRequestMethod("GET");
      c.setDoOutput(true);
      c.connect();
```

first is not necessary, second,  `c.setDoOutput(true);` is changing request method to POST ...
and thats why you're getting 405 method not allowed ...

Comment: Thanks this seems to work with iis. I shall make sure i test with Apache before accepting.